# SharePoint 2013 database .bak file how to restore

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup, restore

I have got a .bak file (database backup) of a SharePoint environment.  However when I restore this file in the database and add this db as a content database I get "0" site collections.  What am I doing wrong in this? am I using this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Before adding it to the server, launch the [Test-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff607941.aspx) script on the restored content db.

If you got errors, then check your restored db and try to fix the errors, or sometimes, it might be just a corrupted backup, try to backup it again.

If everything is ok (just got warnings), then launch the [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff607581.aspx) to mount your content db with a web application. It should go fine.

Comment: I tried Mount-SPContentDatabase.  It mounts but it gives the Current Number of SiteCollections as 0.  I know there should be more than 1 site collection in this backup.  Just to test things out I created a site collection under a different web application.  Took a backup of the database using SQL Server Management Studio.  Then restored the database under a different name using SQL Server Management studio and finally mounted the database to a different web app.  I still get 0 site collections.  I think I am missing a step here.

Comment: Did you run the Test-SPContentDatabase command ? Try it please before the Mount-SPContentDatabase and check if there are no issues.

Answer (score 0):

the SharePoint farm service account must be a member of the SQL Server dbcreator fixed server role. To attach a content database to a Web application, the SharePoint farm service account must have db_owner permission for the content database.

Ref : [For more information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff628965(v=office.14).aspx/)